# Memcache doesn't set keys

Tags: php, memcached, set

I am having a problem with Memcache being unable to set a key. Basically I have my testing page:

```
$db=new db;
$my_test_cache=$db->query("SELECT `txt` FROM `lang` WHERE `pg`='front' LIMIT 2", 10);
```

And a db class for caching:

```
class db {
        public function query($query, $ttl=30, $cache=true, $compr=false) {
            global $memcache;
            if ($cache==true) {
                $res=$memcache->get(hash('md4', $query));
                if ($res!=false) {
                    echo 'this is cached';
                    return $res;
                }
                else {
                    $res=mysql_query($query);
                    $memcache->set(hash('md4', $query), $res, $compr, $ttl);
                    echo 'this is not cached<hr>
                    Query: ',$query,'<br/>
                    Md4: ',hash('md4',$query),'<br/>';
                    var_dump($res);
                    return $res;
                }
            }
            else return mysql_query($query);
            unset($res, $query);
        }
    }
```

Sadly, this does not set any data to cache, even though all the resources seem to work properly. AKA my page outputs:

- this is not cached Query: SELECT * FROM `lang` WHERE `pg`='front'
  LIMIT 2
- Md4: 34aa4e46a15413f5091dac79c9e86306
- resource(7) of type (mysql result)

Would anyone be so kind as to tip me off on what to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

```
        if ($cache=true) {
                  ^--- should be ==
```

As well, unless memcache is far smarter than I think it is, you're simply cacheing a query result handle, not the actual query results:

```
       $memcache->set(hash('md4', $query), $res, $compr, $ttl);
                                           ^^^^
```

At that point, $res is just a randomish number, NOT the `txt` field you requested. You have to first FETCH a row from that result in order to retrieve the data:

```
       $result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
       $txt = $row['txt'];
```

Comment: Ugh, thanks, I've completely forgotten PHP syntax after my break from programming... As for caching, I want to store the mysql resource so that I can do whatever I need to do with it outside. :) thank you

Comment: the mysql resource is going to be meaningless after this script exits. the result handles are PER-SCRIPT, and do not persist outside of the script's own little private world. You can store the result handle, sure, but when some OTHER script pulls up that handle, it's going to be an invalid handle in that script's execution context.

Comment: Another question arises then. my `lang` queries are supposed to fetch multiple rows, how is it possible to store them all then?